# Looking for a program that can manage a searchable database

Tags: database

Is there software that can produce a searchable database with the following information:

- Names of individuals with pictures and other information
- The ability to include comments
- The ability to associate these individuals with other individuals, such as "worked with  X"

Comment: Looking for a local database used in office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called Contact Management Software.  [Act is a good example of that](http://www.act.com/).  Depending on how big your company is, [salesforce.com may also be an option](http://www.salesforce.com/). But that's the term you want to search for.